# Cannot read a Pipeline model with custom unary transformer in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I define a new custom UnaryTransformer (cleanText in the sample code) in Spark and use it in a Pipeline. When I save the fitted pipeline and try to read it back I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test_job$cleanText.read()

When I save and load just the Unary Transformer then it works fine.

Sample code to reproduce the error (tested in Spark 2.2):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.UnaryTransformer
import org.apache.spark.ml.param.DoubleParam
import org.apache.spark.ml.util.{DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable, Identifiable}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.ml.{PipelineModel}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, DataTypes}
import org.apache.spark.util.Utils
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineStage}
import org.apache.spark.ml.param._

object test_job {
   
  class cleanText(override val uid: String) extends UnaryTransformer[String, String, cleanText] with DefaultParamsWritable {
    
    def this() = this(Identifiable.randomUID("cleantext"))
        
    override protected def validateInputType(inputType: DataType): Unit = 
      require(inputType == StringType)
        
    
    protected def createTransformFunc: String => String = {
      val regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]".r
      s => regex.replaceAllIn(s, m => " ")
    }
    
    protected def outputDataType: DataType = StringType
         
  }
    
  object cleanText extends DefaultParamsReadable[cleanText]
    //{
    //  override def load(path: String): cleanText = super.load(path)
    //}
    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("test_job"))
    val sqlc = SparkSession.builder.appName("test_job").getOrCreate()
    import sqlc.implicits._
    
    val cleaner = new cleanText()
    cleaner.setInputCol("word").setOutputCol("r_clean")
    
    val someDF = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      (1, "sample text 1"),
      (2, "sample text 2"),
      (3, "sample text 3")
    )).toDF("number", "word")
    
    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(cleaner))
    
    val pipeline_fitted = pipeline.fit(someDF)
    pipeline_fitted.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/model/")
    //Saving just the transformer
    //cleaner.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/model/")
    println("Pipeline saved")
    
    val pl2 = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/model/")
    //Loading just the transformer will work
    //val cln = cleanText.load("/tmp/model/")
    
    println("Pipeline loaded")
    sqlc.stop()
  }  
}
```

Comment: could be related to one of those bugs? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12606 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22198

Comment: @Ioannis can you take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17048 and see if the workaround posted works for you?

Comment: Thanks both for the pointers. @c.fish I indeed use a companion object. This is definitely a Spark issue.

Comment: @loannis It sounds like Databricks may be able to fix this if you raise a support ticket inquiring about the issue!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: The solution was to apply the custom transformers before fitting the pipeline. Then to write the pipeline. I have not checked whether the latest version of Spark resolves this.